# Is there any way to use std::cout when calling a function within a class?

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <string>

class Solution {
public:
    std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> groupAna(std::vector<std::string> strs) {
        std::unordered_map<std::string, std::vector<std::string>> ana;
        for (int i {0}; i < strs.size(); ++i)
        {
            std::string key = getKey(strs[i]);
            ana[key].push_back(strs[i]);
        }
        
        std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> results;
        for (auto it = ana.begin(); it != ana.end(); ++it)
        {
            results.push_back(it->second);
        }
        
//        for (int i {0}; i < results.size(); ++i)
//        {
//            for (int j {0}; j < results[i].size(); ++j)
//            {
//                std::cout << results[i][j] << " ";
//            }
//        }
        return results;
    }
    
private:
    std::string getKey(std::string str) {
        std::vector<int> count(26);
        for (int i {0}; i < str.length(); ++i)
        {
            ++count[str[i] - 'a'];
        }
        
        std::string key {""};
        for (int j {0}; j < 26; ++j)
        {
            key.append(std::to_string(count[j] + 'a'));
        }
        
        return key;
    }
};

int main() {
    std::vector<std::string> strs ({"eat","tea","tan","ate","nat","bat"});
    Solution obj;
    std::cout << obj.groupAna(strs);
    
    return 0;
}
```

I receive this error:

> Invalid operands to binary expression ('std::ostream' (aka 'basic_ostream<char>') and 'std::vector<std::vector<std::string>>' (aka 'vector<vector<basic_string<char, char_traits<char>, allocator<char>>>>'))

This solution is for [Group Anagrams](https://leetcode.com/problems/group-anagrams/) on Leetcode. I'm just using XCode to practice writing out all the code needed, instead of using what Leetcode gives.

My issue comes when calling and trying to print the `groupAna()` function in class `Solution`. I believe the error is telling me what I want to print isn't something you can print, but I have no idea if that's entirely correct.

I'm ultimately trying to print each string inside its respective `vector`. What's commented out was a workaround that gives me what I want, but it doesn't show each word in a `vector`, so how can I tell if it's in the `vector` it's suppose to be in, other than it being in the correct order?

Output is `bat tan nat eat tea ate`

Comment: `std::cout << obj.groupAna(strs);` won't work since the function returns a `std::vector<std::vector<std::string>>`. There's no `operator<<` overload for `vector`s in general.

Comment: "*I believe the error is telling me what I want to print isn't something you can print, but I have no idea if that's entirely correct.*" - that's exactly what it is telling you. There is no overload of `operator<<` that can write a `vector<vector<string>>` to an `ostream` like `cout`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The member function `groupAna` returns a `std::vector<std::vector<std::string>>` but there are no `operator<<` overloads for `std::vector`s. You could output to a `std::ostringstream` instead and then return a `std::string`:

```cpp
#include <sstream>

class Solution {
public:
    // now returns a std::string instead:
    std::string groupAna(const std::vector<std::string>& strs) {
        std::unordered_map<std::string, std::vector<std::string>> ana;
        for (size_t i{0}; i < strs.size(); ++i) {
            std::string key = getKey(strs[i]);
            ana[key].push_back(strs[i]);
        }

        std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> results;
        for (auto it = ana.begin(); it != ana.end(); ++it) {
            results.push_back(it->second);
        }

        std::ostringstream os; // used to build the output string
        for (size_t i{0}; i < results.size(); ++i) {
            for (size_t j{0}; j < results[i].size(); ++j) {
                os << results[i][j] << ' ';
            }
        }
        /* or using a range based for-loop:
        for(const auto& inner : results) {
            for(const std::string& str : inner) {
                os << str << ' ';
            }
        }
        */
        return os.str(); // return the resulting string
    }
// ...
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Leetcode will ask you to implement a given function, and they will try your code with a battery of unit tests, feeding each test with an input and expecting an output. That is, you don't need to print the vector of vectors of strings within the `groupAnagrams` function, but just generate that matrix correctly.

Anyway, should you want to test your code, and print the output from `groupAnagrams`, you could use the `fmt` library. The `<fmt/ranges.h>` header lets you print standard containers. In the case of vectors, it will print them enclosed in square brackets. For your example, notice that you will have inner vectors.

[[Demo]](https://godbolt.org/z/3facdGbsb)

```cpp
#include <fmt/ranges.h>

int main() {
    std::vector<std::string> strs({"eat", "tea", "tan", "ate", "nat", "bat"});
    Solution obj;
    fmt::print("{}", obj.groupAna(strs));
}

// Outputs: [["bat"], ["tan", "nat"], ["eat", "tea", "ate"]]
```

Or, if you want to flatten that structure, apart from the two solutions proposed by Ted Lyngmo (streams and two nested range-based for loops), you could use C++23 ranges.

[[Demo]](https://godbolt.org/z/axWz6Kvj6)

```cpp
#include <fmt/core.h>
#include <ranges>

int main() {
    std::vector<std::string> strs({"eat", "tea", "tan", "ate", "nat", "bat"});
    Solution obj;
    auto&& groups{ obj.groupAna(strs) };
    for (auto&& str : (groups | std::views::join)) {
        fmt::print("{} ", str);
    }
}

// Outputs: bat tan nat eat tea ate
```